# Raycast not hitting the right position unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have been on here forever it feels like and nothing is fixing the issue. So I am relatively new to c# and unity and I set up my weapon and my crosshairs. I went through and set up ray cast and got a impact effect set. When I load in and try to shoot, my impact effect seems to be landing in different positions and it never lands in the same spot. I want to get it to where the effect happens on the target where the crosshairs are.

This line was added after the fact to try and fix it but didn't end up doing anything:

```
 Ray ray = Camera.main.ViewportPointToRay(new Vector2(0.5f, 0.5f));
```

Here's my script

```
using System.Collections;
```

using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class shooting : MonoBehaviour
{

```
public float damage = 10;
public float range = 100;

public Camera cam;
public AudioSource audioSource;
public AudioSource audio1;
public AudioClip clip;

public AudioClip reload;
public float volume = 0.5f;

public ParticleSystem muzzleflash;
public GameObject hitEffect;

void Start()
{
    
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update()
{

    if (Input.GetButtonDown("Fire1"))
    {
        Shooting();
    }

    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.R))
    {
        Reload();
    }
}

void Shooting()
{
    muzzleflash.Play();
    audioSource.PlayOneShot(clip, volume);
    RaycastHit hit;

    Ray ray = Camera.main.ViewportPointToRay(new Vector2(0.5f, 0.5f));

    if (Physics.Raycast(cam.transform.position, cam.transform.forward, out hit, range))
    {
        Debug.Log("Shooting");
    }

    Instantiate(hitEffect, hit.point, Quaternion.LookRotation(hit.normal));
}

void Reload()
{
    audio1.clip = reload;
    audio1.Play();

    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.W) || Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftShift))
    {
        audio1.Stop();
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

- You've created a ray, you need use it.
- `Instantiate` should be in the if block.
- Specify a layer to do raycast, otherwise it can hit any collider in the path.

```
Ray ray = Camera.main.ViewportPointToRay(new Vector2(0.5f, 0.5f));
var mask = LayerMask.GetMask("Enemy");
    
if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit, range, mask))
{
    Instantiate(hitEffect, hit.point, Quaternion.LookRotation(hit.normal));
}
```

- If the effect is still shown at a random place, add some debug code, check the red line in the scene window.

```
void OnDrawGizmos()
{
    Gizmos.color = Color.red;    
    Gizmos.DrawLine(ray.origin, hit.point);
}
```